# Discord.js "Expected token to be set for this request, but none was present"

Tags: node.js, discord.js

i was doing this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2CsSJshmadg&list=PLpmb-7WxPhe0ZVpH9pxT5MtC4heqej8Es&index=2) and when i execute the code to create a command in discord it doesn't work

error :

```
Registering slash commands...
something wrong happen with this command: Error: Expected token to be set for this request, but none was present
```

code :

```
const { REST, Routes } = require('discord.js');

const commands = [
    {
        name: 'mc' ,
        description: 'show the actual number of members in the server',
    },
];

const rest = new REST({ version: '10' }).setToken(process.env.TOKEN_ID);

(async () => {
    try {
      console.log('Registering slash commands...');

      await rest.put(
        Routes.applicationGuildCommand(process.env.CLIENT_ID, process.env.GUILD_ID),
        { body: commands }
      )

      console.log('slash commands were registered without errors')
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(`something wrong happen with this command: ${error}`);
    }
})();
```

(.env is a file where i have my bot token+server id+bot id)

Comment: Have you logged `process.env.TOKEN_ID` to make sure it returns your token?

Comment: yes i fixed it ! ^^